# Clear function isn't doing anything

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, calculator

I made a basic calculator through Javascript and all of the other functions such as add, subtract, etc. are working, but the clear function doesn't do anything and there aren't any errors coming up in developer tools.

I've tried remaining the clear function and even deleting comments but nothing changed.

```
//function to clear the numbers together
function clearNumbers() {

    // make variable for the value of box1
    var value1 = "";

    // make a variable for the value of box2
    var value2 = "";

    // make a variable called total
    var total = "";

    // put total in the output span
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";

    // put a &nbsp; sign in the sign span
    document.getElementById("sign").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
}

<input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clearNumbers();">
```

no error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need set `document.getElementById("box1").value = "";` to clear textbox value.

```js
//function to divide the numbers together
function divideNumbers() {

// make variable for the value of box1
var value1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box1").value);

// make a variable for the value of box2
var value2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("box2").value);

// make a variable called total
var total = value1 / value2;

// put total in the output span
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = total;

// put a &divide; sign in the sign span
document.getElementById("sign").innerHTML = "&divide;";}



//function to clear the numbers together
function clearNumbers() {

// make variable for the value of box1
var value1 = "";
document.getElementById("box1").value = "";
// make a variable for the value of box2
var value2 = "";
document.getElementById("box2").value = "";
// make a variable called total
var total = "";

// put total in the output span
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";

// put a &nbsp; sign in the sign span
document.getElementById("sign").innerHTML = "&nbsp;";}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='box1' />
<div id='sign'></div>
<input type='text' id='box2' />
<input type='text' id='output' />
<input type="button" value="Clear" onClick="clearNumbers();">
```

Comment: thanks worked like a charm!